# A question about injective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module

I need to find an injective module $B$ and a submodule $A$ of $B$ such that $B/A$ not injective.

Answer (score 2):

Let the ring be $R = k[x]/x^2$ where $k$ is a field of characteristic $2$.  Then $B = R$ is injective but if $A = (x)$ then $B/A \simeq k$ is not an injective $R$-module.

Comment: This works for any field; characteristic 2 is not needed.